Shasta daisy leaves becoming soft and turning brown

I have an indoor Shasta daisy plant for about a year now. It hasn't flowered but it was showing pretty good growth since forever.
Recently, I moved to a smaller place and don't know if it was just me noticing it late, but my daisy leaves are getting softer and wilting. I thought maybe it needed a bigger pot or something because it was huge. And yes indeed it needed a bigger pot, it was all circled up in that pot, so I repotted in a bigger one. On the second day, it looked better, like the wilting was reduced but then after some days I again noticed that the leaves were wilting again and leaves were turning brown and dying.
I don't know what is wrong now. I remember when I repotted I didn't loosened the roots because it didn't look like an issue to me.
Recently after my friend's suggestion I tried to loosen the roots a little and I couldn't. the roots have clogged up so I have to break them if I have to loosen them. I don't know what to do now so I would appreciate any suggestions.

Images can be added primarily by using the the editor toolbar. Just click edit on your post and click on the little house icon. This brings up a special interface that allows you to upload an image online (through the imgur hosting service) through us - even from your clipboard.

Are you saying you repotted without giving the spaghetti a haircut?

I didn't back then, but after a week i again did play with the roots, at least loosened half of it and removed the weird roots.

Thank you @kevinskio. I did add pictures :)

Turn it out of its pot and cut it in half - a bread knife usually works well for this - then repot filling in with potting soil. Repot the second half separately if you want, otherwise dispose of it. Water in well, allowing excess water to flow away freely from the base of the pot (always assuming there are drainage holes in the pot). Shasta daisy (like a lot of other herbaceous perennial plants) when grown outdoors makes a spreading patch, but in a pot, it's unable to spread. Even when grown outdoors, when a patch gets too big, digging up and dividing is a commonplace procedure. That said, Shasta daisy is an outdoor plant and will do much better outside.
